# How to create output files using argparse, python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to my script to create an output file to which all lines from the input files which have been processed will be moved to. However I am currently using argparse for this as my code below shows. I had read () that by opening the output file it will be created, hence the use of open(ouput, 'r+') however the below error occurs. Obviously the argparse part is working as file3 is being accepted but why isnt file3 created?

**Exception**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Joinomattic_1.py", line 30, in <module>
    output_file = open(output, 'r+')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file3'
```

**Usage**:

```
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", action='store', dest='output', type=str, help="Directs the output")
output = str(args.output)
output_file = open(output, 'r+')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r+` doesn't create the file if it doesn't exist - the file must already exist. If you plan on   (over-writing/creating) the file each time your program runs, use `w` instead. If you wish to append to the end of an existing file (or create a new file if it doesn't exist) use `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The `'r+'` mode will not create a file if it doesn't already exist. If you just want to output text to a file, use `'w'` mode in open:

```
output_file = open(output, 'w')
```